# AWS Lambda caching layer using Extensions

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-extensions

I have a lambda function that uses SSM ParameterStore values. It queries the ParameterStore and stores the fetched values in Lambda env variables so that next time it can use them from env variables instead of making calls to the ParameterStore which is working fine if the lambda is in a hot-state, but during the cold start still, my lambda is making many calls to ParameterStore during peak traffic and getting throttling exceptions.

I'm looking to reduce the num of calls to the parameter store by having a caching layer, I found [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/caching-data-and-configuration-settings-with-aws-lambda-extensions/) online, but I'm new to Lambda extensions.  I just wanted to check if this caching works between the cold starts or not before I create a POC. please advise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "works between the cold starts"? It will absolutely have to query SSM ParameterStore for each cold start.

Comment: As my Nodejs lambda function is already caching SSM parameterstore values in `process.env`, I want to understand, if is there any benefit of going to lambda extensions for caching or not.

Comment: There's really no benefit unless you need the cache to be smart enough to expire and re-pull the value in a given time period.

Answer (score 1):

AWS has an extension available specifically for caching Parameter Store and Secrets Manager values:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-the-aws-parameter-and-secrets-lambda-extension-to-cache-parameters-and-secrets/